# How to kill a window?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, com

When I click on an ESRI COM toolbar item, it spawns a window - it looks like a Winform.  Since I didn't spawn the window directly, I can't just do an Object.Close() on it.  What technique can I use to delete a window my application spawned, but that I don't have an object reference of?

Comment: i'm curious, whats an esri com toolbar?

Comment: @Gabriel I have a WPF application that has a WindowsFormHost, in this WindowsFormHost is an AxToolbarControl.  Its a  ESRI.ArcGIS.Controls.AxToolbarControl it implements IToolbar - http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/controls/IToolbarControl.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way is using p/invoke.

The easiest way:
Use FindWindow() function to get and HWND for that window (in C# its IntPtr, you can use NativeWindow class as a wrapper - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.aspx#Y114)

Once you have the HWND you can use CloseWindow() to close the window or send a message to the window useing SendMessage(youHWND, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero) (WM_CLOSE = 0x0010).

If your window has a parent (you can use spy++ to find that out) you can find your window in a more precise way using FindWindowEx().

Hope it helps!

Good luck!

p.s.

Just to be REALLY sure you're not by accident killing another application's window unexpectedly (if you use FindWindow or FindWindowEx without a parent) you can use GetWindowThreadProcessId() to make sure that the window belongs to your process!

Comment: I would also check out the WinAPI Code Pack for .Net:
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4906

It MIGHT have what you need (never used it)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't have the window handle you could interop to Win32 and do the following:

In some method call:

```
CallBackPtr callback = WindowEnumeration;
EnumWindows(callback, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Then it will call the following to find the window and close it, just replace <title> with as descriptive a title for the window as you can to prevent closing of windows that were not intended to be closed.

```
private bool WindowEnumeration(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam)
{
    _windowName.Clear();
    if (GetWindowText(hwnd, _windowName, _windowName.Capacity) != 0)
    {
        if (_windowName.ToString().Contains("<title>"))
        {
            PostMessage(window, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The information for calling Win32 can be found in MSDN or [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/)

Comment: Please don't do that. All the top-level windows whose captions merely *contain* `title` will receive a `WM_CLOSE` message, regardless of where they come from or who they belong to. Imagine what would happen if `title` was something common, like e.g. `Document`. Consider matching the whole caption, and also the window class if at all possible.

Comment: @Hamidi - I added clarification to provide a descriptive title.  I just copied a piece of code I was using for something else already where I do have a descriptive window title.  In my case I did try to specify the window class as well based on Spy++ but then it would never find the window for some reason.